# How to make a world map with a coloured ocean and transparent land surface?

Tags: graphics, geography

I'd like to make a world map with a blue coloured ocean and transparent land surface (to be used later as an overlay). With:

```
map = GeoGraphics[
  CountryData["World", {"SchematicPolygon", "Equirectangular"}], 
  GeoRange -> {{-90, 90}, {-180, 180}}, GeoBackground -> Transparent]
```

I get the opposite, i.e. ocean is transparent and land is coloured. How can this be reversed?

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
polygon = CountryData["World", "SchematicPolygon"];
image = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling[{"GeoImage", image}], polygon}, GeoBackground -> LightBlue, GeoRange -> "World", GeoProjection -> "Bonne"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Better if both images have the same dimensions. Anyway.

```
p = CountryData["World", "Polygon"];
rose = Import["ExampleData/rose.gif"];
mask = Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], p}];
blueOcean = ColorReplace[mask, White -> Blue];
ImageAdd[ImageMultiply[rose, ColorNegate@mask], blueOcean]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks! This works; however the resulting mask and final graphic is no longer a GeoGraphics object. I'd like to keep it that way because I'd like to subsequently also project the graphic using one of the projection transformations of Mathematica 10.

Comment: Sorry, only version 9 here...